# How secure is to store encryption keys or SSH Keys on LPAR?

Tags: key-management, virtualization

I want to store SSH keys (used to connect to some devices that have sensitive data) and the encryption/decryption keys of a database application. They will be inside a [LPAR (logical partition)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LPAR) in our mainframe.

I'm worried about security: does the fact that LPAR resides in the same machine (same hardware) as other virtual serves implies that there is some security risk ? Could an app running on a different virtual server get access to my server and read my keys ?

Comment: Can you update your question with some context? What are you protecting?

Comment: 1) SSH keys for SFTP connection keys  2) Keys used for password encryption/decyrption

Comment: Sorry - what I meant was what information or assets are you protecting? What is their value? Are they credit card or personal sensitive data, or military secrets etc...

Comment: 1) SSH keys used for connecting to internal devices holding sensitive data 2)Encryption/decyrption keys for database credentials(stored at application server)

Answer (score 2):

For such small question, a small answer: even [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_partition_%28virtual_computing_platform%29) is your friend:

> IBM mainframe LPARs are Common Criteria EAL5 certifiable, equivalent
>   to physically unconnected servers, so they support the highest
>   security requirements, including military use.

And it also points to some docs from ibm: [this link, for example](https://www.google.com/search?q=ibm+lpar+security) can give you a lot of information.

Comment: The problem with IBM's statement is it only applies to correctly configured LPARs under a subset of use cases. We have successfully retrieved data from LPARs due to slight misconfigurations, re-use of passwords and other techniques, so while EAL5 is a possible, do not assume anything...

Comment: @RoryAlsop : I agree with you, and I wouldn't trust to use anything without a proper configuration, training, consulting... well, that applies to almost everything about security. But it was a very small question, without that much context, and LPAR can be secure if properly used

Comment: Absolutely - you got an upvote from me anyway :-)